# How to use `destroyOnUnmount: false` and `forceUnregisterOnUnmount: false` with `enableReinitialize: true`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a wizard form which I use for creating and updating a form. I am using `redux-form/immutable`.

When I navigate from tab1 to tab2 of a wizard form I am losing the state (user inputs) in tab1 of a form

I have tried using `destroyOnUnmount: false` and 
`forceUnregisterOnUnmount: false` without `enableReinitialize: true` it works fine for update screen but for create screen I am unable to initialise the form with existing values fetched from API in that case.

`FUNCTIONAL FORM COMPONENT`

```
const AlphaForm = () => {

  return (
    <Panel theme="light">
      <PanelHeader>FORM</Panel.Header>
      <PanelBody>
        <Field
          component={Check}
          label="abc"
          name="abc"
          type="checkbox"
        />
        .....................................
      </PanelBody>
    </Panel>
  );
};
```

`Wrapper`

```
let AlphaFormWrapper = reduxForm({
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: false,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  form: 'alphaForm'
})(AlphaForm);
```

`Connect`

```
const AlphaConnect = connect(
  state => {
    return {
      initialValues: state.getIn(['alphaForm'])
    };
  },
)(AlphaFormWrapper);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `enableReinitialize: true` with `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true` solved the above issue for me